# Cryptographic invariant maps

Tags: elliptic-curves, isogeny, bilinear-pairing

In [[BGK+18]](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/665.pdf) in section 4, Boneh et al. write that:

> For any choice of ideal classes
> $\mathfrak{a}_1,\dots,\mathfrak{a}_n,\mathfrak{a}_1',\dots,\mathfrak{a}_n'$
> in ${Cl}(\mathcal{O})$, the abelian varieties \begin{align}
>  (\mathfrak{a}_1 \star E) \times \dots \times (\mathfrak{a}_n \star E)
>  \text{ and } (\mathfrak{a}_1' \star E) \times \dots \times
>  (\mathfrak{a}_n' \star E) \end{align} are isomorphic over
> $\mathbb{F}_q$ iff $\mathfrak{a}_1 \cdots \mathfrak{a}_n =
>  \mathfrak{a}_1' \cdots \mathfrak{a}_n' $ in ${Cl}(\mathcal{O})$. In
> particular: \begin{align} (\mathfrak{a}_1 \star E) \times \dots
>  \times (\mathfrak{a}_n \star E) \cong
>  (\mathfrak{a}_1\cdots\mathfrak{a}_n) \star E \times E^{n-1}
>  \end{align}

There is no proof in the paper and I did not succeed proving this myself. Can someone point me to a proof for these assertions?

Comment: This is proved in the paper in Appendix A.4, at least up to the "if" part, and provides a reference for the "only if" part. See theorem A.1 which proves the second equation you mentioned, and then proves the first from it.